# How to check whether particular type of file present in my device

Tags: android, file-type

How to check whether any particular file type is present in my device. eg i want to know where any video,  audio or images files are present in my device.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html).